# Express routers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am developing content preprocessor on NodeJS
I have 3 concrete ways of preprocessing:

- building html
- building xhtml
- building xml

Each way is very different from each other (different middlewares)
So I initialized 3 routers:

```
  var xmlRouter = express.Router();
  var xhtmlRouter = express.Router();
  var htmlRouter = express.Router();
```

All I need is to dispatch each request to concrete router.
I can't use app.use() to mount each router because of stripping effects on my url:

```
// Binding
app.use(/\/\S*\.fast\.xml(?=$)/, xmlRouter);
app.use(/\/\S*\.xhtml(?=$)/, xhtmlRouter);
app.use([/\/\S*\.html(?=$)/, /\/\S*\/(?=$)/], htmlRouter);
```

I will loose my url that I need to know further. No way

So is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but as it won't fit into a comment I write it here in the answer section.

IMHO it should work that way:

```
var xmlRouter = express.Router();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   if( req.url.match(/\/\S*\.fast\.xml(?=$)/) ) {
      //if the url matches, pass the res, res, next to the xmlRouter
      xmlRouter.handle(req, res, next); 
      //if handle does not work try: xmlRouter(req, res, next)
   } else {
      //otherwise pass it to the next registered route
      next();
   }
});

//do the same for the other routers
```

Maybe there is an error in this sample because I could not test it, but I think the idea should be clear.

Comment: Seems to be perfect answer. Thank you mr. t.niese

Comment: @Artem great that it works. I had a look at the docs, and it seems that `handle` might be private, so please check if `xmlRouter(req, res, next)` would work too and if so, then please use this instead of `handle`  I'll update my answer as soon as I can test it myself.

Comment: perfect:
`// Bindings
            app.use(function(req, res, next) {
               if( req.url.match(/\/\S*\.fast\.xml(?=$)/) ) {
                  xmlRouter.handle(req, res, next);
               } else if( req.url.match(/\/\S*\.xhtml(?=$)/) ) {
                  xhtmlRouter.handle(req, res, next);
               } else if( req.url.match(/\/\S*\.html(?=$)/) || req.url.match(/\/\S*\/(?=$)/) ) {
                  htmlRouter.handle(req, res, next);
               } else {
                  next();
               }
            });`

Comment: forgot to remove handle